# How to put an ALT value into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this line of code:
     `<img src="images/kaart1.jpg" alt="images/kaart16.jpg" width="110" height="180" onclick="showDiv(event)">`

Now I want to store the value of alt into a variable. I tried:
  `var $img = getElementsByTagName("img")[0];`

That gives an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementsByTagName is not defined

Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: If you can, do yourself a service and use jQuery. It'll be all alot easier.

Comment: you should use [`data-attibutes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead of `alt` to store values.

Comment: try: document.getElementsByTagName...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function `getElementsByTagName`. There is a method of the `document` object which you were trying to use:

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

This will select the first image on the page. If you want to be more specific give an image a unique ID and use `document.getElementById('image-id')`. When you have your image you can access `alt` value using via image object property:

```
var alt = img.alt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that with `document` object,

```
var $img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
```

Since you have tagged this question with jquery, I would like to suggest the jquery way for this,

Try

```
var $img = $('img:first');
var altValue = $img.attr('alt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, it's pretty easy...

`var altAttr = $("img").attr("alt");`

Although you may want to grab it based on a class or id so you aren't grabbing all images...something like

`var altAttr = $("#imgID").attr("alt");`

Comment: I have no idea.  You gotta love it when someone votes your answer down and gives no explanation...lovely.

Comment: They probably thought you were suggesting jQuery incorrectly when it was actually specified in as a tag in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you have `jQuery` as a tag, and you want the `alt` you could...

```
var imgAlt = $("img:first").attr("alt");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please use. document object with getElementByTagName() method as .


 var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
     img.setAttribute("alt","your alt text");
```